# configuring axis in core plot

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot

Here is the screenshot of graph...
In this graph the minimum value of y-axis is 0(at origin) and the maximum value is 700.
I want to set the mininmum value to 500 and maximum value to 700.
[image: here is the graph]

how it can be achieved??
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Try using this if you are using core plot

```
 CPXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
 plotSpace.yRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation: 500 length:200   ];
```

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 steps to be done,

```
1. Setting the orthogonalCoordinateDecimal, this is the point where your graph starts

   CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
   y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromFloat(500.0);

2. Setting the plotRange, this is to determine where should the graph start and its range

   CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;   
   plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:500 length:200];
```

Comment: i am trying to set the origin of y-axis to 500,but through your method distance between the two ticks gets broader and by orthogonalCoordinateDecimal we can change the position of y-axis intersecting x-axis.

Comment: what is your x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal ?

Comment: You need to set the  y.majorIntervalLength also

Comment: it is 0 for x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal

Comment: in this example, it should be x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal you are changing, not y.

Comment: this helped out a whole lot! and noRema's comment on changing x to y did the trick!